# how / can I count selected options in twig?

Tags: twig

Is it possible to count selected options (radios) in twig ? how ?

I have the below drupal webform form (yaml sample provided below) and it's a container/group ( `abqs` ) of radio type questions ( `ab_1`, `ab_2` etc ), each with two options (a, b).

I want to count the *selected* `a` and *selected* `b` options. For example, in the below given sample there are 7 questions and if 3 questions have option `a` selected (i.e. 4 `b` selected) then the result should be: Count `a` : 3 and Count `b` : 4

Is this possible at all in twig ? I've been searching for days and trying many variations to no avail.

I tried :

```
{% set ab_qs = abqs | filter((v,k) => k starts with 'ab_') %}
ab_ qs count: {{ ab_qs | length }} <br /> {# this is printing correctly #}
selected a count: {% set aqs = ab_qs | filter(v => v == 'a') %} {{ aqs|length }} <br /> {# this is giving 0 #}
selected b count: {% set bqs = ab_qs | filter(v => v == 'b') %} {{ bqs|length }} {# this is giving 0 #}
```

Here is the full yaml sample as tried in webform:

```
abqs:
  '#type': wizard_page
  '#title': 'selected options length/count'
  '#open': true
  ab_1:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  ab_2:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  ab_3:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  ab_4:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  ab_5:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  ab_6:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  ab_7:
    '#type': radios
    '#title': 'choose one'
    '#options':
      a: a....
      b: b....
    '#required': true
  abscore:
    '#type': computed_twig
    '#title': 'Selected a/b Counts'
    '#template': |
      {% set qs = elements.abqs %} 
      {% set ab_qs = qs | filter((v,k) => k starts with 'ab_') %}
      ab_ qs count: {{ ab_qs | length }} <br />
      selected a count: {% set aqs = ab_qs | filter(v => v == 'a') %} {{ aqs|length }} <br />
      selected b count: {% set bqs = ab_qs | filter(v => v == 'b') %} {{ bqs|length }} 
    '#ajax': true
```